# Windows 10 bootloader is not showing up in grub menu

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, xubuntu, windows-10

I recently purchased a lenovo machine which was preinstalled with windows 10 os . I installed Ubuntu 16.04 along side with win10 .after little research on internet I am able to boot to Ubuntu .But in grub ,windows 10 bootloader is not listed at all. instead of that windows recovery environment is listed .If I click that option an following error comes "Windows failed to start .A recent hardware or software is might be the cause"

Please suggest me a solution

Comment: did you install ubuntu in EFI mode?

Comment: I am not sure about that .How can I check this

Comment: start ubuntu, look for the folder /boot/efi

Comment: I suggest you need to disable in your bios settings the fast startup and secure boot, then in your ubuntu system perform this command, sudo grub-mkconfig -o /boot/grub/grub.cfg - This assumes you installed windows in UEFI as well as Ubuntu.

Comment: @ravery iam able to see two files inside boot/efi linuxx64.efi.stub and systemd-bootx64.efi

Comment: you appear to have a stub loader not grub installed. did grub error during the install? also windows loader is missing. did you make a new EFI system partition?

Comment: Grub2 is installed .Didn't got any error while installation .I can see grub menu during booting

Comment: ok you should have /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu/grubx64.efi

Comment: From Ubuntu you cannot see /boot/efi/EFI/ubuntu as fstab mounts with 0077 permissions (none). Boot-Repair changes back to defaults so it can update ESP, and installs prior to 14.04 used defaults. Probably to improve secuity as FAT32 has no Linux permissions.  But if fstab has mount of ESP (/EFI/ubuntu) to /boot/efi then it is an UEFI install. Or you can check from live installer. Or just run Boot-Repair and post link to summary report. https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was due to Ubuntu was not installed in UEFI mode. Ubuntu should be installed in the same mode as the primary OS (in my case it is Windows).

[This link](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/UEFI) solved my problem.